# Translating Multiplication Algorithm from pseudocode to C

Tags: c, algorithm, pseudocode

I don't think I've translated the following pseudocode to C correctly:

```
multiply(a[1..p], b[1..q], base)                           // Operands containing rightmost digits at index 1                         
product = [1..p+q]                                         //Allocate space for result                 
for b_i = 1 to q                                           // for all digits in b                                   
  carry = 0
  for a_i = 1 to p                                        //for all digits in a                               
    product[a_i + b_i - 1] += carry + a[a_i] * b[b_i]
    carry = product[a_i + b_i - 1] / base
    product[a_i + b_i - 1] = product[a_i + b_i - 1] mod base
  product[b_i + p] += carry                              // last digit comes from final carry               
return product
```

That pseudocode contains the algorithm needed for "long multiplication" ( the multiplication method taught in school ), I've tried to translate it to C, but did not make it into a function and did use some testing values for a[1..p] and b[1..q].

C code:

```
 int a [2] = { 0, 3 };
 int b [2] = { 0, 2 };

 int product [4];

 int b_i;
 int a_i;
 int product_i;

 for ( b_i = 0; b_i < 2; b_i++) {
    int carry = 0;
    for ( a_i = 0; a_i < 2; a_i++) {
            product[a_i + b_i - 1] += carry + ( a[a_i] * b[b_i] );
            carry = product [a_i + b_i - 1] / 10;
            product[ a_i + b_i - 1] = product[a_i + b_i -1] % 10;
    }
    product[b_i + 2] += carry;
 }
for (product_i = 0; product_i < 4; product_i++ ) {
    printf("%d", product[product_i] );
}
```

The numbers chosen ( 30 and 20 ) display the correct answer, however it does not work for all numbers, as it should.

Comment: When you are translating array indices from 1-based to 0-based, you must be careful to identify _everywhere_ to make that change.  It's not just in your looping arguments, but in the indexing itself.  For example, `product[a_i + b_i - 1]` is undefined behaviour in your program.

Comment: `int product [4];` is an *uninitialised array* yet the first time you use it is with `+=`. Please enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: (1) Recompile this with the flags `-Wall -Werror`. I think it'll be illuminating. (2) Please provide a [mcve], including input that gives erroneous output.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 int product [4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
for ( b_i = 2; b_i > 0; b_i--) {
int carry = 0;
for ( a_i = 2; a_i > 0; a_i--) {
        product[a_i + b_i - 1] += carry + ( a[a_i-1] * b[b_i-1] );
        carry = product [a_i + b_i - 1] / 10;
        product[ a_i + b_i - 1] = product[a_i + b_i -1] % 10;
   }
product[b_i - 1] += carry;
}
```

this avoids pointing below a[0] and b[0]